# Configuration files in public folder of React application return 404 when using a nested route on Azure Static Webapp

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've had an issue recently with a nested route on a react application on a hosted Azure static webapp. Our application route usually looks something akin to `development/application/{location}`, with the routing looking something like this and with the `<Header/>` containing an `<Outlet/>` component:

```
 <Routes>
          <Route path={"/"} element={<Header />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="transactions">
              <Route index element={<Transactions />} />
              <Route path=":filter" element={<Transactions />} />
            </Route>
            <Route
              path="*"
              element={<Navigate to={"/"} replace={true} />}
            />
</Route>
```

All of the routes work, bar `:filter` which fails to download our `config.js`, `manifest.json` and `main.{x}.js` files from the `/public` folder. Our `index.html` works fine, however we have a front-door rule on Azure that supplies the file if the URL contains `/application`

In my attempts to fix this, I've added a `staticwebapp.config.json`, however this wasn't needed to get any of the other routes working. My only experiment has been to try the `rewrite` and `redirect` within the `routes` array to try and get `manifest.json` working, however have had no successful attempts, with `manifest.json` returning either multiple times on routes "home" and "about" that would work previously, or still returning `404` when navigating to `development/application/transactions/:filter`

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
        "route": "/manifest.json",
        "rewrite": "/manifest.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

From my understanding, the routes "home" and "about" are also nested, but don't have any issues in retrieving the files listed above, so I'm a bit stuck as to why it only fails on the `:filter` route. For some reason, it looks to append an additional part of the url, so for `development/application/home`, the `GET` for `config.js` accesses the file at `development/application/config.js`, however for `development/application/transactions/:filter`, Azure tries to find the file at `development/application/transactions/config.js`

Ideally, I'd like a solution which works in either the React application or as a setting on Azure. I'm a bit apprehensive of adding another front-door rule similar to the one we have on the Azure webapp that I previously mentioned for `index.html`, as I'm concerned if we require anything further in the `/public` folder, then the issue will still remain.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if you need any more information to help answer the question :)